# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener How to get relative X,y position in the item

Tags: android

I am trying to implement two regions in my listview row. Region 1 is 75% area horizontly and region2 is 25% area. I plan to do different actions when user taps on region1 and diff when user taps on region 2.

How to get relative x,y coordinates within the row which is clicked.

Comment: You can use this answer for any view on your listview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095629/raw-coordinates-to-listview-item

Comment: but how would I get the x,y position n first place?

Comment: for any view you can get his location, and you can acces at any view,  `int[] myXY = new int[2]; theViewIwouldgetTheLocation.getLocationOnScreen(myXY);`